# Colons in attributes get truncated by XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to add an attribute with a colon to a new element, but it gets stripped in when saving to the file? I am trying to write it for some legacy app to interpret so I don't have control over the format of the XML. So how do I add an attribute with a colon in it?

```
var element = doc.CreateElement("item");
element.SetAttribute("name", "Something");
element.SetAttribute("type:this", "MyClass.Somewhere");
```

Currently, the above ends up as `<item name="Something" this="MyClass.Somewhere" name="Something" />` but I would like it to result as `<item name="Something" type:this="MyClass.Somewhere" />`. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can't have a colon in an attribute name. What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to use an XML namespace?

Comment: No I am trying to modify an XML file from a legacy CMS system. I have no control over the format of the XML. I'm just trying to clone a node and modify it.

Comment: Is there a definition of the "type" prefix in the file somewhere? Maybe something like `xmlns:type="someUri"`?

Comment: Yes there is! <rootConfig xmlns:config="urn:jugnut:configuration" xmlns:type="urn:jugnut:configuration:type">

Comment: @TruMan1: Add the attribute with that namespace. It should work then (even if the prefix will differ), just specify the namespace `urn:jugnut:configuration:type`.

Comment: Wow it worked! Thank you!! Pls leave an answer and I will accept. I had to send 3 parameters with the namespace as the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre)'s Comment:

Add the `attribute` with that `namespace`. It should work then (even if the prefix will differ), just specify the `namespace urn:jugnut:configuration:type`